# How to get Product Last Update DateTime from Facebook API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

In Facebook API using this endpoint:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/product-catalog/products/

I would like to get the date of last edit available in Facebook Business Manager in the extra information:
[image]

Using the graphql explorer https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/, I'm able to get most of the information I need but not this one:

> /{CATALOG_ID}/products?fields=additional_variant_attributes,ar_data,age_group,commerce_insights,condition,currency,custom_data,custom_label_0,fb_product_category,expiration_date,errors,description,custom_number_4,custom_number_3,custom_number_2,custom_number_1,custom_number_0,custom_label_4,custom_label_3,custom_label_2,name,mobile_link,material,ordering_index,origin_country,parent_product_id,pattern,post_conversion_signal_based_enforcement_appeal_eligibility,product_catalog,product_feed,product_group,product_type,quantity_to_sell_on_facebook,retailer_id,retailer_product_group_id,review_rejection_reasons,review_status,price,marked_for_product_launch,manufacturer_part_number,manufacturer_info,inventory,invalidation_errors,importer_name,importer_address,images,image_url,image_fetch_status,image_cdn_urls,id,gtin,gender,custom_label_1,color,category_specific_fields,category,sale_price,sale_price_end_date,sale_price_start_date,shipping_weight_unit,shipping_weight_value,short_description,size,start_date,url,additional_image_cdn_urls,additional_image_urls,applinks,availability,brand,capability_to_review_status,visibility,wa_compliance_category,channels_to_integrity_status,product_sets&limit=10

Is there a specific field not available in the graphql explorer that I need to add? Or another endpoint to get last update time?

Thanks

Comment: My question has been added to Facebook API Community too : https://developers.facebook.com/community/threads/3417795331820196/?post_id=3417795335153529